# WPF Style setter Inputbindings

Tags: wpf, styles, setter, interaction

This code is not issue.
But i want partial InterAction and InputBindings.

```
<Window>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExamCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{Binding WindowKeyDownESCCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Some Xaml Elements ... -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I want do create Window style.

Like this.

```
<Window Style="{StaticResource MyWindowStyle}" />

<Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExamCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{Binding WindowKeyDownESCCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
</Style>
```

Comment: This isnt much to go on. Not sure what trouble you're having, what is the desired output? What is not good about your current output? But I can just give you a generic answer - look up "Style.Triggers" & "DataTrigger".

Comment: @Bandook You can't apply inputbindings via a style, so his window inputbindings in that style will not work.

Comment: @Andy yes thats true, but i dont fully understand what he's trying to do. what I meant was, he can keep his input binding as they are, but move the rest into a style. divide it up depending on what his requirements are - which are not clear and also not sure why he wants that if this works. keep the style (style specific triggers) separate, and whats not allowed in the style - put it elsewhere. They are not allowed via a style for a reason. I just gave him a general place to look to understand Styles better - and know their capability.

Comment: Well yes, his requirements could do with clarification. I also think the interaction triggers will be a problem. Not really explored it but I reckon he'd have to use a template put both on say a contentcontrol.

Comment: Thank you all. I wrote the result of my issue in the answer column below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for my question and I think I probably solved it.

Here.

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                       <!-- Here i:InteractionTrigger -->
                    </ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                    <ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                       <!-- Here InputBindings -->
                    </ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And thank you for your interest in spite of the lack of explanation.

Have a good day!!